# How can I capture a multiline pattern using a regular expressions in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file that I need to parse using regular expressions. The text that I need to capture is in multiline groups like this:

```
truck
zDoug
Doug's house
(123) 456-7890
Edoug@doug.com
30
61234.56
8/10/2003

vehicle
eRob
Rob's house
(987) 654-3210
Frob@rob.com
```

For this example I need to capture truck followed by the next seven lines.In other words, in this "block" I have 8 groups. This is what I've tried but it will not  capture the next line:

```
(truck)\n(\w).
```

NOTE: I'm using the program [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/) to test my regex before I port it to Java.

Comment: If you need to read input line by line, what it has to do with regex?

Comment: @nikita because I want to form groups that include new lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(?m)^truck(?:(?:\r\n|[\r\n]).+$)*
```

This assumes the whole text has been read into a single string (i.e., you're not reading a file line-by-line), but it *doesn't* assume the line separator is always `\n`, as your code does.  At the minimum you should allow for `\r\n` and `\r` as well, which is what `(?:\r\n|[\r\n])` does.  But it still matches only *one* separator, so the match stops before the double line separator at the end of the block.

Once you've matched a block of data, you can split it on the line separators to get the individual lines.  Here's an example:

```
Pattern p0 = Pattern.compile("(?m)^truck(?:(?:\r\n|[\r\n]).+$)*");
Matcher m = p0.matcher(data);
while (m.find())
{
  String fullMatch = m.group();
  int n = 0;
  for (String s : fullMatch.split("\r\n|[\r\n]"))
  {
    System.out.printf("line %d: %s%n", n++, s);
  }
}
```

output:

```
line 0: truck
line 1: zDoug
line 2: Doug's house
line 3: (123) 456-7890
line 4: Edoug@doug.com
line 5: 30
line 6: 61234.56
line 7: 8/10/2003
```

I'm also assuming each line of data contains at least one character, and that the blank lines between data block are really empty--i.e., no spaces, TABs, or other invisible characters.

(BTW: To test that regex in RegExr, remove the `(?m)` and check the `multiline` box instead.  RegExr is powered by ActionScript, so the rules are a little different.  For a *Java*-powered regex tester, check out [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/).)

Answer (score 6):

this pattern should work `((.*|\n)*)`

Answer (score 4):

I think that in order to span multiple lines your Pattern should be compiled in DOTALL mode, something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("truck\\n(.*\\n){7}", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: This regex would be much closer to correct *without* the `DOTALL` flag.  As it is, the `.*` will initially consume the entire rest of the document.  Then it might backtrack a little, but it will still match everything up to the final linefeed.

Comment: Ah, greediness! :-) Missed a "?" at the very end... Thanks a lot for pointing it out!

Comment: There's no need to make the quantifier non-greedy.  Just get rid of the `DOTALL` flag, and the dot will no longer match newlines.